# Macro to automatically record event (Audacity or alternative)

Tags: audacity

I am currently using Audacity to record (gasp) church meetings, but this question could apply to any other event or concert that occurs on a recurring schedule.  I love the timer record option under the transport menu to have it begin recording a few minutes before the event and end a few minutes after, but my volunteers have a hard time remembering to set it up and tend to get confused by the menus (many of them are over 80 years old and not at all tech savy).

I would love to set this up as a macro that runs automatically when audacity is opened, fills in the start and end time, sets the save and export settings for them, and executes the menu.

Is this possible?  If so, how?

I see that I can open the dialog with the TimerRecord macro command, but that does not allow me to preset any of the items.

Also, I don't see how to have the macro auto run on opening audacity.

Any help or pointers are appreciated.  If audacity won't do this, is there an alternative you would recommend (prefer open source, but would consider commercial).

Comment: You didn't tell us what OS you're on, though I assume Windows, of which I have little knowledge. On Mac, you could do this easily with [Audio Hijack](https://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/)

Comment: sox with a cron job.

Comment: Yes, I'm on windows.